# Calling init after short period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a portion of code  that extends a class, the init is never getting called even when I initialize it, is there a way I can call this section after a 1 second delay?

```
$.extend(Header.prototype, {

    init: function () {
        if (!MyClass.Initialized) {
            var script = "$(\".Header\").header(\"init\")";
            setTimeout(script, 1000);
            return;
        }
        this._bind();
    },  ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() { $('.Header').header('init'); }, 1000);
```